# How to refresh UICollectionViewCell's image while bouncing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview, bounce

My image view inside my cell is not refreshing when the collection view is bouncing. I mean the image is being fetched over the network and is sometimes received during bouncing. If the reception completes during bouncing, there is no image refresh. So this basically happens to the last row cells.

Here's my code:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    MyCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"myIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    //[...]
    [cell.imageView setImage:nil];
    if(currentProduct.imageUrl){
        if(currentProduct.image){
            [cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:currentProduct.image]];
        }else{
            NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:currentProduct.imageUrl]];
            AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
            manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
            NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [manager dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest uploadProgress:nil downloadProgress:nil completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                if(responseObject){
                    [[MainController sharedController] updateProduct:currentProduct withImage:responseObject];
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        UICollectionViewCell *updateCell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                        if(updateCell){
                            [collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]];
                        }
                    });
                }
            }];
            [dataTask resume];
        }
    }

    return cell;
}
```

The `reloadItemsAtIndexPaths` seems not to be called (or the collection view doesn't care).
Is there a way to ensure refreshing **while bouncing**? The only solution I came with is:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didEndDisplayingCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    MyCell *myCell = (MyCell *)cell;
    Product *currentProduct = [self.category.products objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if(!myCell.imageView.image && currentProduct.image){
        [collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]];
    }
}
```

*Edit:* By bouncing I mean that scrolling is not brutally stopped when reaching the edges:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "bouncing" ?

Comment: Pull to refresh ?

Comment: You need to use `UIScrollViewDelegate` to get `scrollViewDidScroll:` calls in which you can check the content offset to see if the view is "bouncing".

Comment: Yes, i found that too, but i prefer `didEndDisplaying` as it refers to a cell. That said, might the collection view ends displaying cell before it ends scrolling? Also `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:` could be relevant here.